# Electrical current in walls

Tags: electrical, knob-and-tube

I have an older house, from the mid 20s. Most of the wiring is knob and tube. Since there are brick walls every time i want to hang something I drill a hole for a screw. To avoid electrocuting myself I bought an electrical tester that's supposed to beep near electricity without touching it. I've come to realize that in large parts of the house it will go off as if there's a current even when there are no wires under the area of wall I'm near. If I touch the wall with my hand (but not just one finger) then it stops.

My theory is that something is trying to use the wall as a ground.

So my questions are, does that seem like a reasonable explanation and does it seem dangerous?

I've never gotten shocked by touching the walls.

Comment: Is there plaster and lath over the brick walls?

Comment: There is plaster, I'm not positive about lath

Comment: Could be metal lath that's somehow picking up a micro current via induction. Or a crossed wire somewhere. Just as an experiment, I'd suggest you have someone go through all the circuits and see when the tester beeps and doesn't. If that localized a circuit (and you feel competent), inspect all the junction boxes to see if anything obvious is amiss.